# Reactjs. Element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKeo4.jpg)

[Context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRdVc.jpg)

[ProductList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1vHv.jpg)

[Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfCPL.jpg)

I can't find the mistake. Help!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to put in code and question in your description and refrain from putting code in an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with following code, you need to refactor to not mix up your prop names with the component name.

[image: problem code]

You are mixing up `Product` value in your map function with the component named `Product` and you are also passing it a prop named `Product={Product}`, so at the time of rendering, React dont know what `<Product>` is within the context of the map function as at that time `Product` is actually a value of the current iteration.

You can refactor this as following or whatever fits your needs:

```js
{ value => value.products.map(product => <Product key={product.id} currentProduct={product} /> }
```

Comment: As I said you need to put your error message and code block in your question else it will be closed later.